# Can't get value of Object in Javascript , nodejs, stripe library

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, stripe-payments

Im trying to get a value "status" from "customer" object with this simple script:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(customer.subscriptions.data.plan.status));
```

When i execute this function, the console returns me:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
```

"customer" Object:

```
customer: {
"object":"customer",
"created":xxxxxx,
"id":"xxxxxxx",
"livemode":false,
"description":null,
"email":"xxxx@xxxx.com",
"shipping":null,
"delinquent":false,
"metadata":{},
"subscriptions":{
    "object":"list",
    "total_count":1,
    "has_more":false,
    "url":"/v1/customers/xxxxxxxxx/subscriptions",
    "data":[{
        "id":"xxxxxxxxx",
        "plan":{
            "interval":"month",
            "name":"xxxxxx",
            "created":xxxxx,
            "amount":xxxxx,
            "currency":"eur",
            "id":"6month",
            "object":"plan",
            "livemode":false,
            "interval_count":6,
            "trial_period_days":null,
            "metadata":{},
            "statement_descriptor":null,
            "statement_description":null},
            "object":"subscription",
            "start":xxxxx,
            "status":"active",
            ...,
```

Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Please quote the object using copy-and-paste, and in its entirely, and formatted consistently (rather than, for instance, having that near-hidden`}` after `"statement_description":null`), which makes things *quite* misleading.

Answer (score 4):

The error doesn't match up with the data. It should be that it can't read `status` of undefined. This is because `customer` does have `subscriptions`, and `subscriptions` *does* have `data`, but then you're treating `data` as though it had a `plan` property, which it doesn't. `data` refers to an *array*, the first entry of which has a `plan` property. Also note that `status` is not a property of `plan`, it's a property of the same object that `plan` is a property of.

So accessing the *first* entry's `status` would be:

```
customer.subscriptions.data[0].status
// Note -------------------^^^
```

If there are subsequent entries in `data`, they would be at indexes 1, 2, 3, etc.

Example:

```js
var customer = {
  "object": "customer",
  "created": "xxxxxx",
  "id": "xxxxxxx",
  "livemode": false,
  "description": null,
  "email": "xxxx@xxxx.com",
  "shipping": null,
  "delinquent": false,
  "metadata": {},
  "subscriptions": {
    "object": "list",
    "total_count": 1,
    "has_more": false,
    "url": "/v1/customers/xxxxxxxxx/subscriptions",
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "xxxxxxxxx",
        "plan": {
          "interval": "month",
          "name": "xxxxxx",
          "created": "xxxxx",
          "amount": "xxxxx",
          "currency": "eur",
          "id": "6month",
          "object": "plan",
          "livemode": false,
          "interval_count": 6,
          "trial_period_days": null,
          "metadata": {},
          "statement_descriptor": null,
          "statement_description": null
        },
        "object": "subscription",
        "start": "xxxxx",
        "status": "active"
      }
    ]
  }
};
document.body.innerHTML = customer.subscriptions.data[0].status;
```